# How to overlay multiple images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to overlay multiple images that are the same size using Python. Currently, I'm using the images module and can overlay two images at once like so:

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open'/path/to/image1.png'
img2 = Image.open'/path/to/image2.png'  
Image.alpha_composite(img1, img2).save('/new/image.png')
```

But if I'm going to want to put lots of images together... that'll get rather tedious right? I want to know if there's a better way of going about this.

Comment: You're missing parents around the class to `Image.open`. And why not make a function that does this and then use it in a loop?

Comment: The computer doesn't really care how tedious a process is.

Comment: You could create a list of paths to the images to be overlaid and then process the list. You could even a a list-of-lists to perform batch processing if you wished.